# Does Android maintains any exception info when application crashes?

Tags: android, exception, logging

I hope title itself says what my question is.

My app is crashing at very rare scenarios like nearly 1 out of 100 times.
I am not using any crash log tools and not logging exception causes.

I want to know does Android system maintains any crash log report when the app is crashed either in System level or in App level.

Thanks

Comment: You can check it using LogCat, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Android system maintains a crash report and sends to the developer but the user has to allow this.

[image: Crash and Report]

And then you can check it here in [Android Developer Console](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fapps%2Fpublish%2F&ei=YZ51VObsLdbVar2mgJgK&usg=AFQjCNEvG-AI0sojdmEeraO9D_b4Xtsn6g&bvm=bv.80642063,d.d2s):

[image: Crash report in Developer Console]

As an alternative you can use third-party loggers like [Liquid](https://lqd.io), [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com/) (mention in another answer), [Splunk MINT Express (ex-Bugsense)](https://mint.splunk.com) or any other from this [links](http://www.getapp.com/alternatives/crashlytics-application)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, if you can't debug it in real time with the IDE (DDMS and LogCat), you must use Crashlytics or any other similar tool.
I use it in all my apps, it is very useful.